# controller receiving null data from view CRUD

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-binding, ef-core-3.0

I have two models like this :

```
  public class Student
    { 

    public string StudentId{get;set;}
    public String StudentName{get;set;}
    public StudentStatus StudentStatus{get;set;}

    }

 public class StudentStatus
    {
        public string StudentStatusId{get;set;}
        public string StudentStatusTitle{get;set;}
    }
```

I have a view model :

```
 public class StudentCrudModel
    {
        public Student Student{get;set;}
        public IEnumerable<StudentStatus> StudentStatuses{get;set;}
    }
```

I then have a view to create a new student

```
 @model StudentDatabase.ViewModels.StudentCrudModel
    <h1>Create</h1>

    <h4>Department</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-action="Create">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Student.StudentName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Student.StudentName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Student.StudentName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Student.StudentStatus" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Student.StudentStatus.StudentStatusId" class="form-control">
                @foreach (var status in Model.StudentStatuses)
                {
                    <option value="@status.StudentStatusId">@status.StudentStatusTitle</option>
                }
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Student.StudentStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
```

In my controller the post method to create a new student I have this

```
    public async Task<IActionResult>  Create([Bind("StudentId,StudentName,StudentStatus,StudentStatus.StudentStatusId")] Student student){
//code that creates a student
}
```

My problem is that in the controller method to create the student, the method is getting null regardless of the values i input in the view when i load the application, My model binding is not working. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try changing the controller parameter? Did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In the View you have `@model StudentDatabase.ViewModels.StudentCrudModel` but in the controller you have

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("StudentId,StudentName,StudentStatus.StudentStatusId")] Student student)
```

Try putting

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("StudentId,StudentName,StudentStatus.StudentStatusId")] StudentCrudModel student)
```

instead, just reference `StudentCrudModel` instead of the `Student` object in the parameters

Comment: can i ask another question related to this in the comment or do i have to post another question

Comment: What is the question?